# Take a spark dataframe and collect all rows into one single row

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

is there a way to take a relational spark dataframe like the data below:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "foo"),  
        (2, "bar"),
    ],
    ["id", "label"]  
)

df.show()
```

And collect all of the values (I don't care about the column names) into one column so it looks like below

```
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(["1 foo 2 bar"], "string").toDF("new_column")
new_df.show()
```

I do need to keep the order, so it has to be a string of '1 foo 2 bar', and not '1 2 foo bar' for example.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes try with **`concat_ws()`** and **`collect_list() + array_join()`** functions.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo"),(2, "bar"),],["id", "label"])

df.withColumn("temp", concat_ws(" ", *df.columns)).groupBy(lit(1)).agg(array_join(collect_list(col("temp"))," ").alias("new_column")).\
  drop("1").\
  show(10,False)
#+-----------+
#|new_column |
#+-----------+
#|1 foo 2 bar|
#+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df2=spark.sql("select id,label,lead(id)over(order by id) as id_1,lead(label)over(order by id) as label_2 from df  ")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
df3=spark.sql("select concat(CONCAT(id, ' ',  label)  ,  ' ',concat(id_1 ,' ', label_2)) as one_col from df2 where id_1 is not null")
df3.show()


+-----------+
|    one_col|
+-----------+
|1 foo 2 bar|
+-----------+
```